# Newton's law doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Consider the following arrangement

[image]

When I drew the FBD of block C then I got a doubt that why tension in string pulling C backwards cannot be equal to force F. I know it is against what actually happens but why is it so.

Why can't tension be equal to force F? Is it because we know that when we pull a block in such a way , it accelerates so there must be some horizontal force for the same ?

Comment: Why do you think the tension is different from $F$?

Comment: @Mauricio why can't rope pull block back by force F

Comment: Is block C moving?

Comment: @Mauricio the surface is frictionless, my teacher drew the diagram and said find acceleration of C, and at that time I got doubt why it is necessary for C to move i.e. why can't tension be equal to force F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the surface is frictionless, I guess you would agree that an external force is going to make the whole system move (to the right in your diagram) as nothing is stopping the whole system from moving.

If the system moves, block C moves too (the strings have constant length). The forces over block C are the force $F$ and the tension $T$. If $T=-F$ then there is no movement. Which means that $T\neq -F $ is the only possible solution.

Comment: OH so I didn't realize that all three blocks can together be taken as system also, thankyou for answering my query,+1